# MFF 8.0 invokeProcedure ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm migrating MobileFirst Web(Javascript) application developed in MFP7.1 to MFF8.0. When call a Javascript adapter, the following error happens. Does anyone give an advise how to fix the problem?

Error Message:
ibmmfpf.js:2040 Uncaught ReferenceError: extendWithDefaultOptions is not defined
    at __WLClient.invokeProcedure (ibmmfpf.js:2040)

Code:

```
var proc = function(procedure, parameters) {
    return WL.Client.invokeProcedure({
        adapter: ‘XXXXXXX’,
        procedure: procedure,
        parameters : (parameters || [])
    }, {
        timeout: 60000
    });
};

var standardHandler = function(res) {
    if (typeof res.responseJSON === 'object' && res.responseJSON.code > 0) {
        return $.Deferred().reject(res).promise();
    }
    return $.Deferred().resolve(res).promise();
};

////  invoking proc
return proc(‘getYYYYY’).then(standardHandler);
```

Comment: Please use WLResourceRequest to make adapter calls in 8.0 . The documentation can be found here : https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Some of the APIs from MFP 7.1 have been changed in MFP 8.0.Use [Migration Cookbook tool](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migration-cookbook/).This tool helps you by identifying areas in your codebase that you will need to inspect and alter, such as APIs that are deprecated, no longer supported, or modified.

For more details about migration IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 - 7.1, to IBM Mobile Foundation 8.0. see below links

[Migrating apps from earlier releases](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.upgrade.doc/upgrade/t_upgrade_to_80.html)

[Migrating apps and adapters to MobileFirst Foundation 8.0](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/migrating-apps-and-adapters-to-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/)

[Developing for Cordova application](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/cordova-tutorials/)